# How to design a class method can only be invoked once

Tags: c++, class, oop, design-patterns

I have stateful class, once a class instance is created, its Bar function/method can only be called once otherwise the internal state will mess up. How to design such thing?

Something can warn/error at compile time would be better.

```
class  Foo {
  bool Bar(string arg...) { do something...}

  // some class member 
  string s;
  int i;
}
```

Comment: private variable in the class `bool bar_called_ = false; ` and `bool Bar () { if (bar_called_) return false;  // or throw exception ` followed by `bar_called = true;`

Comment: Thanks Dave, I just edited the question: something at compile time would be preferred. I saw several things in code: 1. comments says it should use once. 2. reset the state when invoke Bar().

Comment: My guess is anything at compile time would probably just hide the above in a macro or class or similar or would make Bar part of the constructor, but perhaps someone else will offer a suggestion.

Comment: I fear you cannot achieve that behaviour at compile time, at least not if you want to be able to call Bar from an arbitary part of your project.

Comment: This technique is generally called "typestate programming" and can (as far as I know) only be done in a language that has a linear type system (ie where you can remove "used up" variables from the scope). Here is an [example in Rust](http://cliffle.com/blog/rust-typestate/) and [an approximation in C++](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/09/24/expressive-code-for-state-machines-in-cpp/)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a static flag inside `Foo::Bar()` that keeps track of whether or not the function has already been called:

```
bool Foo::Bar() {
   static bool has_been_called; // initialized to false

   if (!has_been_called) {
      has_been_called = true
      // ...
      // do something
      // ...
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

For the case that multiple threads may call the member function, you can 
 use [`std::call_once()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) instead; as the read of the flag `has_been_called` above is not synchronized with the write.

```
bool Bar() {
   static std::once_flag flag;

   bool executed = false; 

   std::call_once(flag, [this, &executed]() {
      // ...
      // do something
      // ...
      executed = true;
   });
   return executed;
}
```